# How exactly does the constant $C$ in the Sobolev inequality depend on the domain?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The Sobolev inequality theorem -as stated [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&lpg=PP1&dq=evans%20partial%20differential%20equations&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=evans%20partial%20differential%20equations&f=false)- says

> Let $U$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, with a $C^1$ boundary. Assume $u \in W^{k,p}(U)$. If $k<n/p$ then $u \in L^q(U)$, where $$ \frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{k}{n}. $$ We have in addition the estimate $$ \Vert u \Vert_{L^q(U)} \leq C \Vert u \Vert_{W^{k,p}(U)} $$ the constant C depending only on $k,p,n$ and $U$.

---

My **question** is: How does $C$ depend on $U$ exactly? Does it depend only on the measure of $U$? Is it independent of translation of $U$?

---

The reason I'm asking this is that I am able to estimate solutions to some PDE as $$ \Vert u \Vert_{L^q(B(x,1))} \leq C \Vert u \Vert_{W^{k,p}(B(x,1))} $$ for some $q,k,p$ and any $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$. However, I need a uniform bound, i.e. a bound not depending on the center $x$ of the balls $B(x,1)$. So if the Sobolev inequality depended only on the measure of $U$, I'd be fine.

---

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177240/dependence-of-the-sobolev-embedding-constants-on-the-domain) is a similar question, but I really don't understand the answer.

Comment: I guess $C$ might depend on the shape of $U$, too. Since you need an assumption on $\partial U$, the constant could depend on the geometry of $\partial U$, at least *a priori*.

Comment: Well the shape stays the same for my balls $B(x,1)$. The question is: does it depend on the position $x$ of the balls?

Comment: Yes, your question is less general than it appears to be. I would say that the best constant is independent of the center $x$, but I do not have a reference to suggest.

Comment: Can't you just translate the function by $x$ and then back again? Unless I'm missing something the constant is obviously independent of $x$ since $B(x,1)$ and $B(y,1)$ are isomorphic in every sense we could care about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be a rigid motion: translation, rotation, reflection, or composition of such things. Then $|D^k u\circ T|=|D^k u|\circ T$ for derivatives of all orders.  Using this and the change of variables formula (in which the absolutely value of Jacobian is $1$), you will find that the neither side of $\Vert u \Vert_{L^q(U)} \leq C \Vert u \Vert_{W^{k,p}(U)}$ is affected by the transformation $T$. Thus, the best Sobolev constant is preserved under rigid motions.

The scaling is trickier, because it affects the derivatives of different orders differently. I  think the behavior of optimal $C$ in $\Vert u \Vert_{L^q(U)} \leq C \Vert u \Vert_{W^{k,p}(U)}$ under scaling can be pretty complicated. What is true is that one can give an upper bound on $C$ that depends (besides the indices $m,p,q$) only on the parameters of the *cone condition* satisfied by $U$. See *Sobolev spaces* by Adams for details.

Scaling is more tractable for a related inequality $\Vert u \Vert_{L^q(U)} \leq C \Vert D^ku \Vert_{L^{p}(U)}$, which holds for $u\in W^{k,p}_0(U)$. Indeed, here replacing $u$ with $u(\lambda^{-1}  x)$ contributes the factor of $\lambda^{n/q}$ on the left and $\lambda^{-k+n/p}$ on the right. So, if the domain is scaled by $\lambda$, the constant $C$ gets multiplied by $\lambda^{k-n/p+n/q}$. Observe that $k-n/p+n/q\ge 0$ here, with equality for the borderline Sobolev exponent.

That larger domains have larger constants for $W^{k,p}_0(U)$ inequalities is obvious, because $W^{k,p}_0(U)\subset W^{k,p}_0(V)$ when $U\subset V$. Such monotonicity does not hold for $W^{k,p}(U)$ inequality, which is sensitive to the shape of the domain in a subtle and mostly intractable way.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by *user90090*, it can be told that in *Sobolev spaces* by Adams, as well as in its version by Adams–Fournier, no appropriate details are to be found. The details of dependence of the best Sobolev constant on parameters of the *cone condition*,  usually referred to by experts in the field as well-known, belong to what is now called *Mathematical folklore*, *i.e*, something like *check-it-youself-if-you-need* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_folklore). Cited from *Mathematical folklore*, the details look like this. For a domain $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ of diameter $D$, star-shaped *wrt* some ball $B\subset U$ of diameter $d$, the best Sobolev constant depends only on the ratio $d/D$, which is established by scaling argument.  For a bounded domain $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, represented by the Gagliardo lemma as a union of $N\geqslant 2$ domains $U_i\,$, each star-shaped *wrt* some ball $B_i\subset U_i\,$, the best Sobolev constant depends only on $N$ and the ratios $d_i/D_i\,$.